# Increase gap between ticklabels and axis labels in 3D, Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I've seen similar questions to this before but the answers only seem to apply to 2D plots.

I've increased the font size of both my ticklabels and axis labels to make my plot more readable, but now the two labels overlap.  Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

for label in ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels() + ax.get_zticklabels():
    label.set_fontsize(16)

ax.set_xlabel('Applied Field (mT)', fontsize = 20, labelpad=30)
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (K)', fontsize = 20, labelpad=30)
ax.set_zlabel('$M / M_s$', fontsize = 20, labelpad=30)
```

I've tried putting `plt.rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 12` immediately after the preamble but that didn't seem to have any effect, amd it doesn't have an option for the z-axis.

And the option `labelpad =` in `ax.set_label()` doesn't seem to have an effect on the distance between the ticklabels and axis labels.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:  Instead of asking if I'm doing something wrong, I'd like to ask whether there is a way of doing this in 3D.

Thanks.

Comment: `labelpad` argument currently dose nothing in `3D`. The document actually said so, http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html.

Comment: @CTZhu So is there a way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: @user3087409 did you find any solution to increase the gap between xticklabel and lable?